# how to pass the cookie in request node js library

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I am currently using a request to call the HTTP request using [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request)

it's working fine. my question is how to pass the cookie?

this is the code which i did,

```
 export function triggerSimpleAjax(
  url,
  type = 'POST',
  req_data,
  onSuccess,
  onFailure,
  headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
) {
  const request = require("request");
  const jar = request.jar();
  const cookie = request.cookie("name=John");
  jar.add(cookie);
  let options = {
    url: url,
    method: type.toUpperCase(),
    headers: headers,
    json: req_data
  }

  // console.log('********************************** API Starts here **********************************');
  request(options, (error, response, body) => {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      onSuccess(response.body);
    } else {
      if (typeof onFailure === 'function') onFailure(response.body);
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a cookie jar and add the cookie there, and send it with the request.

```
const request = require("request");
const jar = request.jar();
const cookie = request.cookie("name=John");

//Doesn't work anymore jar.add(cookie);
jar.setCookie(....);
request({
  uri: "...",
  method: "...",
  jar: jar
}, function(error, response, body) {
  console.log(body);
});
```

**MAJOR EDIT:**

`request` uses [`tough-cookie`](https://github.com/salesforce/tough-cookie) now, so the syntax is:

```
jar.setCookie(cookieOrString, currentUrl, [{options},] cb(err,cookie))
```

Also there is a `sync` counterpart:

> **.setCookieSync(cookieOrString, currentUrl, [{options}])**
>   Synchronous version of setCookie; only works with synchronous stores (e.g. the default MemoryCookieStore).

Comment: that one was i have tried but jar.add is shown as undefined